# iib 10 missing message on the local mq queue using mqoutput node

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

I'm newbie on IBM tool.
On my laptop, I have installed IIB v10 using a local MQ manager. I created 2 local queues on MQ: "Queue.In" and "Queue.Out".
I have a very simple scenario that I work on: I send a 'csv' file on the "Queue.In", get the message using 'MQInput node' transform the message into xml using 'mapping node', and then put the xml message to 'Queue.Out'.
Using the ‘flow exercicser’ I’m able to send my ‘csv’ file and I can see that the message get consumed and transformed to xml and send to “Queue.Out”
Problem: My xml message is successfully put in "Queue.Out", but disappear right after.
I want it to remain in the "Queue.Out".
I use “MQ explorer” to browse my queues.
Please advice.

Comment: It seems the flow exerciser is taking the output message. Try some other testing tool to send the input message, like rfhutil.

Comment: Thanks a lot Attali. I did As you said, I downloaded 'Rfhutil' and used to send messages to queue and to browse message. And yes indeed my message was there. Any idea why flow exerciser is taking away the message? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I would always recommend using Rfhutil for Delivery and Subscription of messages onto/out of a queue. In Rfhutil you can also browse messages without taking them off the queue which can be useful. 
I am unsure why the flow exerciser removes messages - this is a new feature in IIB10 so it might be that they wanted queues to be cleared after the flow execution has been completed to avoid clogging queues. I believe the point of the exerciser is to track the logic of the flows themselves not to get messages. 
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. Yes indeed it helps having a better understanding.